# KeyError this says that key(partner) is not in dict?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make an chat application using python and django. I almost complete it and its working fine for 8-10 minutes when two persons are chatting after that certain time it shows an error.

here is the traceback : -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "\Django_chat\django_chat\chat\views.py", line 55, in receive

    message = chatSession.getMessage(request.session['partner'],request.session['uid'],afterTime)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py", line 47, in __getitem__

    return self._session[key]

KeyError: 'partner'
```

here is the receive module :-

```
def receive(request):
    # message received by this user
    chatSession = chat()
    data = request.POST
    afterTime = data['lastMsgTime']
    try:
        message = chatSession.getMessage(
            request.session['partner'],
            request.session['uid'],
            afterTime)
    except:
        #partnerId = virtual_users.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).partner
        print('there is an error in receive request')
        traceback.print_exc(file=open("/myapp.log","a"))
    msg = serializers.serialize("json", message)
    return HttpResponse(msg)
```

Please Help me :(
thanks
Ansh J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the user's session got timed-out and hence the `request.session` doesn't have `partner` or `uid` values in it.

Sessions get timed out based on the (lack of) activity on them. Reading a session is not considered activity for expiration purposes. [Session expiration](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views) is computed from the last time the session was modified. By default, Django only saves to the session database when the session has been modified -- that is if any of its dictionary values have been assigned or deleted. To change this default behavior, set the `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` setting to True. If `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST`  is True, Django will save the session to the database on every single request.

Comment: did you set `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` to `True`? Are you sure the user is in fact logged in?

Comment: It works sorry for the last reply actually i have install 2 versions of python and made the changes in wronge one thats why it doesnt work that but now its working.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

`print 'request.session contains ', repr(request.session)`

in your `except` suite. Is the dictionary missing anything other than an item with `'partner'` as key? Is it empty? Whatever, try to work out how/why it became like that.